# array_replace_recursive with custom function like Lodash mergeWith

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I need a function to do same as array_replace_recursive but new created value stay an empty string.

```
JSON 1
{
    "test1":"test1",
    "test2":"test2"
}

JSON 2 before
{
    "test1":"test1"
}

JSON 2 after
{
    "test1":"test1",
    "test2" : ""
}
```

Do you have any idea ?

*I'm testing with a personnal recursive function, to be continued* ^^

(like https://lodash.com/docs/#mergeWith)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you got any examples for us to work on? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Is a good resource on how to ask a question so that the community can help you! :-)

Comment: I added an example, I search other solution and I test at the same time :D

Comment: You should search and/or try your own solutions first and then show what you've tried. It is inappropriate to ask others to do the entire work for you.

Comment: if in the 1st array "test1":"test**3**",?

Comment: @Narf The result of my first search is array_replace_recursive, but when I have test the first once, I saw that the new key haven't empty, and I have again searched, without concrete result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$a = [
    'foo' =>
    [
        'bar' => 'Stool',
        'bat' => 'Cricket'
    ]
];

$b = [
    'foo' =>
    [
        'bar' => 'Tat'
    ],
    'qux' => 
    [
        'quux' => 'Cross'
    ]
];

array_walk_recursive($b,
    function(&$v) {
        $v = "";
    }
);
$c = array_replace_recursive($a, $b);

var_export($c);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'foo' => 
    array (
    'bar' => '',
    'bat' => 'Cricket',
    ),
    'qux' => 
    array (
    'quux' => '',
    ),
)
```